# DeviceUseTrigger in Suspend event in Universal App returning DeniedBySystem

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, prism, win-universal-app

In my universal windows app which is using prism, I currently have a background task that is started with a DeviceUseTrigger.

Starting/stopping the background task by clicking a button from the UI (as most of the online samples demonstrate) is working fine.

However, I would like the task to start when the app is suspended (either via a home screen button press, or an app switch) and I would like it to stop when the app is resumed.

In my App.xaml.cs file, I have hooked up the MvvmAppBase Suspending and Resuming events, and I am calling the start/stop code in the relevant places.

However, when I suspend my app the DeviceTriggerResult returned by the RequestAsync function is DeniedBySystem.

This is different from the Allowed state which is returned when the start code is called from a button click.

My initial thought was that the code needs calling on the UI thread, but using the dispatcher to do that gives the same result.

Any ideas?